# SQL combining results

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query below return values of an 1 to many relationship between customers, addresses and plans

```
SELECT customers.name, 
  addresses.address, 
  plans.state, 
  plans.created, 
  plans.updated
FROM addresses INNER JOIN plans ON addresses.id = plans.address_id
 INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = addresses.customer_id
```

The query will return the data in the format bellow:

```
    name    |   address     |   state   |   created     |   updated
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Larry Smith |   123 St.     |   Active  |   04/20/2016  |   04/20/2016

Larry Smith |   123 St.     |   Inactive|   03/20/2016  |   04/20/2016

Larry Smith |   123 St.     |   Inactive|   02/20/2016  |   03/20/2016

Jane Doe    |   456 St.     |   Inactive|   03/20/2016  |   04/20/2016  

Jane Doe    |   456 St.     |   Inactive|   02/20/2016  |   03/20/2016
```

I want it to show the data where each customer are shown only once. The created field is the date of the first plan created and updated field is the update of the last plan and the state field is the state of the last plan

here is the example:

```
    name    |   address     |   state   |   created     |   updated
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Larry Smith |   123 St.     |   Active  |   02/20/2016  |   04/20/2016

Jane Doe    |   456 St.     |   Inactive|   02/20/2016  |   04/20/2016
```

I tried using Distinct or Group by on the address but since the plans have different IDs it will still show multiple entries per customers and also it does not address the requirement of combining the dates on the plan in a single record

**EDIT**
Clarification: I'm using Postgresql

I tried this query based on the queries provided by Gordon and Firetonton and some documentation on postgresql

```
SELECT customers.id, customers.name, 
  addresses.address, 
  FIRST_VALUE(plans.state) OVER w,
  MIN(plans.created) as created_plan, 
  MAX(plans.updated) as cancelled_plan
FROM addresses
 INNER JOIN plans ON addresses.id = plans.address_id
 INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = addresses.customer_id

WINDOW w as(
  PARTITION BY plans.state ORDER BY plans.updated DESC
)

GROUP BY customers.id, customers.name, addresses.address, "plans".state
```

I'm getting `Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider converting those dates to datetime `'YYYY-MM-DD'` for proper aggregation.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: I'm using postgresql. I thought I had that one in. I added it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use aggregate functions MIN, MAX and FIRST(... ORDER BY ...) in complement of GROUP BY :

```
SELECT customers.name, 
  addresses.address, 
  -- With "first" custom aggregate
  -- FIRST(plans.state ORDER BY plans.updated DESC), -- or ...plans.created... if it's your reference
  -- Or with postgres array_agg, makes an array an take the first value
  (array_agg(plans.state ORDER BY plans.updated))[1] AS last_state,
  MIN(plans.created), 
  MAX(plans.updated)
FROM addresses
 INNER JOIN plans ON addresses.id = plans.address_id
 INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = addresses.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.name, addresses.address
```

Comment: I think I would have to create these as separate lookup queries. One for MIN(plans.created) and another for MAX(plans.updated). The way I see is that max plan will aggregate a set of data that is different from min. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: No you havn't to. Try this request, It Will produce thé result you want with thé data you wrote. What this request mean is "group result by customer and, for each group take thé lowest value of created and thé highest value of updated". Thé first( ... Order by ... ) is à little more tricky, It virtually sort thé rows by updated field inside a group (e.g. for each customer) and take thé status value of thé first one. Is It more clear for you ?

Comment: wow it did work out pretty good. I have to comment the FIRST statement otherwise I get this `function first(character varying) does not exist`

Comment: Ok, so the SGDB you use seems to not implement the _first_ aggregate function (actually, only postgresql support it I think). So to give you a full answer I need to know which SQDB you use : MySQL ? SQLite ? SQLServer ? MariaDB ? Other ?

Comment: I looked at postgresql doc and it does not seem to have the function FIRST

Comment: My bad, first and last are custom aggregates, here is a [link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)) to create them if you want. Otherwise, in order to use standard postgres sql you can use array_agg and take the first value (I have edited my answer in this way)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use aggregation for this.  I am going to suggest conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name, address, 
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then state end) as last_state,
       min(created) as created, max(updated) as updated
FROM (SELECT c.name, a.address, p.state, p.created, p.updated,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY p.updated DESC) as seqnum
      FROM addresses a INNER JOIN
           plans p
           ON a.id = p.address_id INNER JOIN
           customers c
           ON c.id = a.customer_id
     ) apc
GROUP BY name, address;
```